# Get values of two different columns based on a condition in a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a certain condition (`Incident = yes`) and I want to know the values in two columns fulfilling this condition. I have a very big data frame (many rows and many columns) and I am looking for a "screening" function.

To illustrate the following example with the `df` (which has many more columns than shown):

```
Repetition  Step    Incident   Test1   Test2
1            1         no         10     20
1            1         no         9      11
1            2         yes        9      19
1            2         yes        11     20
1            2         yes        12     22
1            3         yes        9      18
1            3         yes        8      18
```

What I would like to get as an answer is

```
Repetition   Step
1              2
1              3
```

If I only wanted to know the Step, I would use the following command:

```
df[df.Incident == 'yes'].Step.unique()
```

Is there a similar command to get the values of two columns for a specific condition?

Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) option for the condition, select the interested columns, and finally remove duplicate values

```
 df.query('Incident=="yes"').filter(['Repetition','Step']).drop_duplicates()
```

OR

you could use the Pandas' [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method, set the rows as the condition, set the columns part with the columns you are interested in, then drop the duplicates.

```
df.loc[df.Incident=="yes",['Repetition','Step']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: `df[df.Incident=='yes'][['Repetition','Step']].drop_duplicates()` - Can be achieved without `loc`

Comment: @nishant, avoid chained indexing. Have a look at the Pandas doc : [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: I don't think this is relevant for the question here, as there is no assignment taking place. Same results are achieved using above comment.